# How to update property of 1st instance of class whenever 2nd instance's property get updated?

Tags: c#

I have 2 classes derived from base class in which it is writing to text file (file name passed while instantiating) .

While I write with 2nd instance I want to write to first instance too.
How it will be achieved ?

e.g.

```
TestStepLogger = new Logger(TestStepLogFile);
DebugInfoLogger = new Logger(DebugInfoLogFile);
```

Logger Class has Log() method which writes to file (TestStepLogFile and DebugInfoLogFile)
I am using TestStepLogger and DebugInfoLogger individually to log some data.
Requirement now is whatever I will log() through TestStepLogger , need to get written under DebugInfoLogFile too.

Existing output=
TestStepLogFile :
"Step 1"
"Step 2"

DebugInfoLogFile :
"Application started"
"Applied some settings"
"Updated Files"

---

Required output =
TestStepLogFile :
"Step 1"
"Step 2"

DebugInfoLogFile :
"Application started"
"Applied some settings"
**"Step 1"
"Step 2"**
"Updated Files"

Comment: Sample code really helps with questions like these, since it'll show how you're actually instantiating and using the classes (and, ideally, why you need to "write to [the] first instance too", which is not clear from your textual description).

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you are talking about two instances or two classes?

Comment: seems like your logger should be able to write to multiple files. No need for two independant loggers

Comment: that's good solutions but Logger class is in another project , I am just sending text file name (e.g.TestStepLogFile)  and in log("") method sending text.

Answer (score 0):

That kind of link between the logs... I agree with MakePeaceGreatAgain. I suggest you combine the two to a single logger class, with two files as input. on the first method you simply call the second method. No need for unnecessary complications.

When you create a class, it should be as independent as possible. If the two logs are so interlinked, decoupling them simply doesn't make sense, and making one affect the other an adhock solution to a simple problem: needless OOPs implementation. Code should be as easily understood and maintainable as possible. If all the logger does is as described, then making more than one is preferably avoided.

Comment: Please provide a full answer. As it stands this "answer" should be a comment. Thanks

Comment: @BinaryWorrier ,This should be acceptable?